# GTK3 - any way to customize broadwayd?

Tags: html, gtk, html5-canvas, gtk3

I have a GTK3 client used to connect to server for management. It is not as simple as web-interface as user have to download client and install some libraries in order to run it.

So I remembered about broadway HTML5 backend. But there is no additional info about it since I last tried it a year++ ago.

I found out what can cause segfaults - for example, tray icons, some shadows is better to disable. Bit what about HTML title etc? Official docs says nothing at all, only how to run it.